# PHP mysql responsive combobox without refreshing the php page

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

If I select the `Elementary` in department combo box the Grade 1 and Grade 2 will only show in the grade level combo box and so in High School which is Grade 7 and 8. I did it using ajax and create another PHP(`selectgradelevel.php`) page for selecting and I don't want to create and include another PHP page just for selecting the data. What I want is put the `selectgradelevel.php` code on the page only

```
`department_table`

|---------------------|------------------|
|    department_id    |   departmentName |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |     Elementary   |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |     High School  |
|---------------------|------------------|

`gradelevel_tbl`
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|    gradelevel_id    |   gradelvlName   |  department_id   |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |     Grade 1      |        1         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          2          |     Grade 2      |        1         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          3          |     Grade 7      |        2         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          4          |     Grade 8      |        2         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

**department combo box**

```
 <select name="departmentlvl" id="departmentlvl">
  <option value="" >Choose Department Level</option>
    <?php
        $qry="Select * from department_tbl";
        $result=mysqli_query($conn,$qry);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
        extract($row);
        echo "<option value='".$department_id."'>".$departmentDesc."
  </option>"; }?> 
</select>
```

**gradelevel combo box**

```
 <select name="gradelevel" id="gradelevel">
    <option value="">Choose Grade Level</option>
        <?php include('selectgradelevel.php')?>
</select>
```

**selectgradelevel.php**

```
<?php
 $deptlvl = $_POST['departmentlvl'];
        $qry="Select gradelevel_id, gradelevelDesc from gradelevel_tbl 
        where department_id = '$deptlvl'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$qry);
        while($row =mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
        extract($row);
        $gradelevelid=$row['gradelevel_id'];
        $gradelevel=$row['gradelevelDesc'];?>
        <option value="<?php echo $gradelevelid?>"><?php echo $gradelevel?>
   </option><?php } ?>
```

**ajax code**

```
  $(document).on('change','#departmentlvl',function(){
         var val = $(this).val();
         $.ajax({
               url: 'selectgradelevel.php',
               data: {departmentlvl:val},
               type: 'GET',
               dataType: 'html',
               success: function(result){
                    $('#gradelevel').html();  
                    $('#gradelevel').html(result); 
               }
          });
   });
```

Comment: Actually this is the right way to do it

Comment: is there no other way to prevent the creating too many php pages? becausing ill be using same combobox function but different tables in my project

Comment: Make it parametric and use the same files several times

Comment: How? sorry i'm a beginner